# Django sqlite database not gettitng created in local machine and in remote getting Secret key Error

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I am having the below settings for database in settings/base.py. The behaviour is different in both my local Mac OS X and in ubuntu for the same code.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../database/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

In local OS X machine, i experience the below error:

```
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/p_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 207, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

In ubuntu server, where i try to host it for test, it shows below error.

```
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/p_live/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Full error code is in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/ERw0cJPm

Kindly help here. I checked the database folder both in local and server, this is not getting created.

Answer (score 1):

**OSX Issue:**

Make sure that your django server process has access to write on the configured location.

**Ubuntu Issue:**

The `manage.py` module can't load the settings file configured in it. You can try after explicitly adding the `--settings=<project_name>.settings.py`

```
(p_live) user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx:~/sites/site.com/source$ python manage.py runserver --settings=<project_name>.settings.py
```

`<project_name>` = Pacakage name (or Django project name) where settings.py exists.

Comment: The server now works, Wondering why expliict settings are required as I have only one django project & dont have multiple ones to switch.